# Can't open a .story file for jbehave in eclipse 3.6.2

Tags: java, eclipse, jbehave, jbehave-plugin

I've created a new project to test JBehave with an eclipse plugin. When I try to open the story file (sample.story) I'm getting the following error and the file doesn't open.

Message: Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.jface".

Exception Stack Trace:

```
    java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
at org.jbehave.eclipse.preferences.PreferencesHelper.getHelper(PreferencesHelper.java:5)
at org.jbehave.eclipse.preferences.ProjectPreferences.<init>(ProjectPreferences.java:47)
at org.jbehave.eclipse.JBehaveProject.initializeProjectPreferencesAndListener(JBehaveProject.java:86)
at org.jbehave.eclipse.JBehaveProject.<init>(JBehaveProject.java:64)
at org.jbehave.eclipse.JBehaveProjectRegistry.getOrCreateProject(JBehaveProjectRegistry.java:79)
at org.jbehave.eclipse.editor.story.StoryEditor.getJBehaveProject(StoryEditor.java:302)
at org.jbehave.eclipse.editor.story.StoryEditor.dispose(StoryEditor.java:132)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPartHelper(EditorReference.java:705)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPart(EditorReference.java:465)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference.getPart(WorkbenchPartReference.java:595)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.getEditor(EditorReference.java:289)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditorBatched(WorkbenchPage.java:2863)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2768)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$11(WorkbenchPage.java:2760)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$10.run(WorkbenchPage.java:2711)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2707)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2691)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2682)
at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:651)
at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:610)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.EditorUtility.openInEditor(EditorUtility.java:365)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.EditorUtility.openInEditor(EditorUtility.java:168)
at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.OpenAction.run(OpenAction.java:229)
at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.OpenAction.run(OpenAction.java:208)
at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.SelectionDispatchAction.dispatchRun(SelectionDispatchAction.java:274)
at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.SelectionDispatchAction.run(SelectionDispatchAction.java:250)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.packageview.PackageExplorerActionGroup.handleOpen(PackageExplorerActionGroup.java:373)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.packageview.PackageExplorerPart$4.open(PackageExplorerPart.java:526)
at org.eclipse.ui.OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper$InternalListener.open(OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper.java:48)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$2.run(StructuredViewer.java:845)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:49)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.fireOpen(StructuredViewer.java:843)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1131)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$6.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1235)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireOpenEvent(OpenStrategy.java:264)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$2(OpenStrategy.java:258)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(OpenStrategy.java:298)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4066)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3657)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2640)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2604)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2438)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:671)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:664)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:115)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:620)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:575)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1408)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the source code of `getHelper` (of some version) I found following references to some field INSTANCE:

```
            InstanceScope.INSTANCE, 
            ConfigurationScope.INSTANCE, 
            DefaultScope.INSTANCE },
```

Unfortunate isn't it?

In every case it means that you compiled against one version, and did run against another version.